# maps are not available after updating lumia 625 to wp8.1

Tags: lumia, 8.1, maps, error

After updating my phone from WP8 to WP8.1, Maps will not open - it just say "Maps are not available on this phone". What can I do?

Comment: Hi! Can you please add some details to your question? A screenshot would be nice, or just report the complete error text. Thank you very much, it will help people in providing you the best answer ;-)

Comment: Also, what country are you in? have you tried HERE maps?

Comment: I've updated maps on 625, running the Cyan update with no problems, which does make me wonder if this is a regional issue?

Comment: @RowlandShaw that's what I'm thinking. HERE maps should have the same issue if that's the case.

Comment: Can you try any other mapping apps like GMaps?